# Custom Form Handling in Wordpress and GAE

Tags: php, wordpress, google-app-engine

I'm trying to impliment a custom form in a Wordpress page. I've set the form up and like so:

```
<form method="POST" action="/handleForm.php">
  <input type="text" name="userName" />

  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

handleForm.php:

```
echo($_POST['userName']);
echo('Fire');
```

app.yaml(in addition to the default Wordpress stuff in there):

```
- url: /handleForm.php
  script: handleForm.php
```

The `handleForm.php` file is in the root folder beside the `app.yaml` file.

When I submit the form, it goes to the correct URL, but nothing happens... I would expect it to `echo` at least `Fire`. Any insight as to what's going on here? Am I missing something with regard to `Wordpress` or `GAE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additional `.php` file has to be in the `root/wordpress` folder and prefixed with `wp-`. For example:

```
root/wordpress/wp-handleForm.php
```

Then the `action` attribute of the `form tag` must be set as `/wp-handleForm.php`.

```
<form method="post" action="/wp-handleForm.php">
</form>
```